# Check the number is in a certain format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex

I have number that needs to be in a certain format: 123-12345678.
three numbers then a dash then 8 numbers.

I'm already checking that only numbers are entered but how do I check that they enter the correct format?

```
function Validate(event) {   
  var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9-]+$");
  var str = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
  if (regex.test(str)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Character " + str + " is not allowed");
    return false;
  }  
}
```

The validate function is called on the each key press:

```
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNumber" onkeypress="return Validate(event);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: `new RegExp("^\d{3}-\d{8}$");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d{3}-\d{8}$
```

Don't check `onkeypress` just check before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You could check substrings of the entered string if they are numeric or dash.  i.e. : `str.substr(0, 3);`  I am not a fan of huge frameworks but if you are using jquery anyway you can do a `jQuery.isNumeric` as a quick solution to check the string part.